# Why GPO won't apply on computer configuration but works fine on user configration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I am beginner and working on new domain server 2012r2 and everything works fine except one think I do not really understand why it is happening all configuration I made on the user configuration node applies fine but when it comes to computer configuration nothing applies

I searched and found I have to run the command `gpresult` and from the below output found that

`Basic Group Policy` I have made applies on the user configuration **ONLY**

`Default Domain Policy` which is created by default when I activate the domain services applies on the computer configuration only for me it was really wired issue that computer linked by default to this GPO while user are not and need to be linked manually and I also do not understand why it created by default ?
and in what it is help ?

why my `Basic Group Policy` GPO not applying on the computer configuration 
I tried to enforce that GPO but that wont help me

another related question 
these two GPO that created by default when activating domain services are they important ? can I delete them ? and on what they will effect if I delete them ?

many question I know but hope someone help I search and I am getting confused
thanks a lot for help

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\it_sam>gpresult

Microsoft (R) Windows (R) XP Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001

Created On 05/23/2018 at 13:31:52


RSOP results for BNK\it_sam on TestPC002 : Logging Mode
------------------------------------------------------------

OS Type:                     Microsoft Windows XP Professional
OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  5.1.2600
Domain Name:                 BNK
Domain Type:                 Windows 2000
Site Name:                   Default-First-Site-Name
Roaming Profile:
Local Profile:               C:\Documents and Settings\it_sam
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=TestPC002,CN=Computers,DC=BNK,DC=net
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 05/23/2018 at 13:16:49
    Group Policy was applied from:      SRV3.BNK.net
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups:
    --------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users


USER SETTINGS
--------------
    CN=Samer Jama Al-Deen,OU=OU - Basic Security Policy,DC=BNK,DC=net
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 05/23/2018 at 13:17:02
    Group Policy was applied from:      SRV3.BNK.net
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Basic Group Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Default Domain Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The user is a part of the following security groups:
    ----------------------------------------------------
        Domain Users
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        LOCAL


C:\Documents and Settings\it_sam>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just how [Group Policy Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374162(v=vs.85).aspx) works:

> Be aware that policy settings are divided into policy settings that
>   affect a computer and policy settings that affect a user.
>   Computer-related policies specify system behavior, application
>   settings, security settings, assigned applications, and computer
>   startup and shutdown scripts.

Computer Configuration settings are only applied to computer objects while User Configuration settings are applied to user objects.

> With [Computer Configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc736413(v=ws.10)) in Group Policy, you can set policies that
>   are applied to computers, regardless of who logs on to the computers.

The citations are from old sources from Windows 2003 times, but I couldn't easily find it repeated anywhere on the current documentation. It's probably just so fundamental that Microsoft has considered it needles to say again.

Comment: so, I have to build two `OU` one for `computer config` and the second for `users config` and link each one for the same GPO ? and I may unlink the default one ?

Comment: am I right or things are not really correct ?

Comment: You could even have the settings in the same GPO and the objects in the same OU. Computer settings are only applied to computer objects in that OU.